# Properly batch items from input channel

Tags: mysql, go

**Use case**

I want to persist a lot data in a MySQL database which I receive via a channel. For performance reasons I process them in batches of 10 items. I receive the input items only every 3 hours.

**The problem**

Assuming I get 10004 items, there will be 4 items left because my go routine waits for 10 items before it "flushes them away" in a batch. I want to make sure that it creates a batch with less than 10 items in case there are no more items in that channel (channel is also closed by the producer then).

**Code:**

```
// ProcessAudits sends the given audits in batches to SQL
func ProcessAudits(done <-chan bq.Audit) {
    var audits []bq.Audit
    for auditRow := range done {
        user := auditRow.UserID.StringVal
        log.Infof("Received audit %s", user)
        audits = append(audits, auditRow)

        if len(audits) == 10 {
            upsertBigQueryAudits(audits)
            audits = []bigquery.Audit{}
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Go and I am not sure how I would properly implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example. When a channel is closed, the range exits, so you can just process any remaining items after the loop.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Audit struct {
    ID int
}

func upsertBigQueryAudits(audits []Audit) {
    fmt.Printf("Processing batch of %d\n", len(audits))
    for _, a := range audits {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", a.ID)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}

func processAudits(audits <-chan Audit, batchSize int) {
    var batch []Audit
    for audit := range audits {
        batch = append(batch, audit)
        if len(batch) == batchSize {
            upsertBigQueryAudits(batch)
            batch = []Audit{}
        }
    }
    if len(batch) > 0 {
        upsertBigQueryAudits(batch)
    }
}

func produceAudits(x int, to chan Audit) {
    for i := 0; i < x; i++ {
        to <- Audit{
            ID: i,
        }
    }
}

const batchSize = 10

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    audits := make(chan Audit)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        processAudits(audits, batchSize)
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        produceAudits(25, audits)
        close(audits)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Complete")
}
```

Output:

```
Processing batch of 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Processing batch of 10
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
Processing batch of 5
20 21 22 23 24
Complete
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use a Timer.
Play with example here https://play.golang.org/p/0atlGVCL-px

```
func printItems(items []int) {
    fmt.Println(items)
    return
}

func main() {
    
    items := []int {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
    ch := make(chan int, 5)

    go func(ch <-chan int) {

        timer := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Second)
        temp := make([]int, 0, 5)

        for {

            select {
            case i := <- ch:
                timer.Reset(1 * time.Second)
                temp = append(temp, i)
                if len(temp) == 5 {
                    printItems(temp)
                    temp = []int {}
                }
            case <- timer.C:
                printItems(temp)
                temp = []int {}
            }

        }

    }(ch)
    
    for k, i := range items {
        fmt.Println("Send ", i)
        ch <- i
        if k == 7 {
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        }
    }

}
```